# NAT client and server, and port closing

Tags: networking, router, ip, nat, private-network

Let's say I have a client and server. Client is behind NAT and server is public.

Client wants to have a **session** with the server.

Let's say client is on 192.168.1.1, NAT on 192.168.1.2 private IP addresses. And NAT on 50.0.0.1 and server on 50.0.0.2 public IP addresses.

Client sends the UDP/IP (hopefully it's similar with TCP/IP) packet to the server. This packet has its source IP 192.168.1.1 and source port let's say 1000 (selected randomly), also has destination port 50.0.0.2 and destination port 2000, as this is the port application runs on the server.

The TCP/IP packet arrives at NAT which changes the source IP to 50.0.0.1 and port let's say 5000 (selected randomly) and routes to the server.

The server sends the response packet with destination IP 50.0.0.1 and port 5000.

The NAT changes the destination IP of the packet to 192.168.1.1 and destination port to 1000.

1. Now, can the server send many UDP/IP packets to the same IP 50.0.0.1 and port 5000, and all packets will be forwarded to the client 192.168.1.1 port 1000?
2. If so, for how long will this port 5000 on the public side of NAT forward the packets to the mentioned client?
3. Only the packets **with the source IP 50.0.0.2 and source port 2000** will be forwarded to the client?

Comment: are you asking about the differances between TCP and UDP as regards NAT? UDP does NAT very differantly than TCP does, since TCP contains information about the virtual circuit that doesn't exist for UDP, so you can't tell that a given packet is part of an existing flow.

Comment: @FrankThomas TCP does NOT contain information about the virtual circuit - and to do this would, at least in part, break dynamic routing used by all very large ISP's.  https://www.techrepublic.com/article/exploring-the-anatomy-of-a-data-packet/ 
shows the contents of a UDP and TCP header and explains how TCP negotiates a reliable connection (using acknowledgements and packet sequences, not virtual circuit information)

Comment: @FrankThomas not to defend what frank is saying, since he said UDP does NAT which is absolute nonsense, but regarding virtual circuits, where he says TCP does contain info on virtual circuit and you say it doesn't. This says it does   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_circuit says  "it is possible to use TCP as a virtual circuit, since TCP includes segment numbering that allows reordering on the receiver side to accommodate out-of-order delivery."

Comment: @barlop What do you mean by "UDP does not do NAT"? And virtual circuit in the sense you mention is not the same as Fran mentions. In your text is about reordering which makes it seam that packet arrive through channel (circuit). But UDP and TCP are the same regarding the identification of the flow - by IP and port number only (although TCP uses both source and destination and UDP only destination).

Comment: @coraf Why would UDP not use source and destination for tracking? I would have thought that without doing source tracking NAT would break quite badly (imagine multiple devices behind NAT all using Google's DNS servers as an example - if you did not track source port I don't see how this could work)

Comment: ok, clearly I misspoke, please substitute the word "Connection" for "virtual circuit". TCP has states of connectivity controlled by flags and syn/ack values that provide ordinality and continuity to a flow of packets (eg you know they are all related to the same flow, and what order they should be in, regardless of what order they arrive in). for TCP NAT uses these characteristics to determine connection states. UDP has to use tricks like timing windows and address matching to determine that a pair of UDP packets are related to each other.

Comment: @croraf I never said that, I never said it did or it didn't, please watch how you quote me.

Comment: @davidgo I was talking about identifying the the packet "flow" as the TCP/UDP concept, that is to know to which UDP flow the packet belongs it uses only the destination. TCP uses both source and destination. This flow identification is actually the socket. Thus TCP does not contain some special identification of the flow comparing to UDP. For "NAT flow" it should use both source and destination. (Sorry, a bit hard to explain what I mean, but I think we are on the same page)

Comment: @croraf - I think we are miscommunicating - My contention is that UDP, like TCP,  must use both the source IP & port and the destination IP and port to route data from clients to server and back.  If it did not use the source IP and port as far as mapping, if you have 2 people doing DNS lookups outside NAT, I don't see how the NAT device could work out which answers were for which client.

Comment: @davidgo Agree!

Comment: @barlop "since he said UDP does NAT which is absolute nonsense"

Comment: @FrankThomas To identify the "response flow" in both UDP and TCP you are using source IP and source port of the return package (source is now the server). No ack/nack sequence numbers or flags help you here.

Comment: @croraf    UDP and NAT are two different things(as you know). There is some interaction/relationship between NAT and TCP, and between NAT and UDP..  For example NAPT is a form of NAT, loads of people use  NAPT, and (as we know), NAPT can be told to let in TCP or UDP on a particular port. But I wouldn't use such clumsy language as to say that one does the other, since to say such a thing, is clumsy at best and at worst(and not just at worst), it makes no sense.  As an analogy, A printer does printing, I wouldn't say a Printer does or does not do a Person, it's incoherent.

Comment: @barlop OK. I understand now what you were thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers:

1. Yes.
2. This depends on the implementation of NAT for the device.  In Linux this can be tuned by [editing /proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_udp_*](http://mobilesociety.typepad.com/mobile_life/2015/06/udp-nat-timeouts-and-how-to-change-them.html)
3. Yes - unless there are "related" ports recognised by NAT, in which case additional NAT modules are used to work out what is related (at least on Linux)